# When passing variables on url %271%27

Tags: php, html, url

This...

```
 header("Location: fichaTorneioFinSub.php?id=" . $_GET['id'] . "");
```

The value of the GET is 1. But I always end up in this page:
fichaTorneioFin.php?id=**%271%27**

The id value gets these %27 around it. I know that means it's an encoded single quote but it shouldn't be there.

Comment: `%27` is a url-encoded `'`. e.g. your query string has probably been double-encoded or something.

Answer (score 1):

This will sound as stating the obvious: if it shouldnt be there, make sure it isnt. This means sanitizing your input ($_get data) into data you expect. Somehow the get variable already contains a single quote so i would suggest checking that first. To get it out you could for example

```
trim($_get ['id'], "'")
```

Comment: My bad it will! Use trim with second param a single quote instead

Answer (score 1):

It would be a good idea to track down what's giving you the lone `'`, but this will ensure you're only working with digits:

```
$id = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $_GET['id']);
header("Location: fichaTorneioFinSub.php?id=".$id);
```